# How to detect if a Node spawned process is still running?

Tags: node.js, spawn

I can spawn a process like:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var topicListener = spawn('python', ['topic_listener.py','Node.js'], {env: {
    TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    TWITTER_TOKEN_SECRET: process.env.TWITTER_TOKEN_SECRET,
    TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN
}});

topicListener.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});

topicListener.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});

topicListener.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log("EXITED " + code);
});
```

So of course I can control it all asycnchronously with `.on(close, ...)` but is there any other way to control if a process is still alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spawn('python', ['topic_listener.py','Node.js']..` Return Child process Object. Use `topicListener.pid` to find unique ID associated with the process if it's alive.

Comment: I already had tested that but even if process was ended pid was still a defined number

Comment: `topicListener.on('close', function (code) {
        topicListener = null;
        console.log("closed" + code);
    }); `                                                                                 

    `topicListener.on('exit', function (code) {
        topicListener = null;
        console.log("EXITED " + code);
    });`
<br/>
    if  `topiclistener` is `null` process is absent.

Answer (score 5):

```
topicListener.on('exit', function (code) { 
 topicListener = null;
 console.log("EXITED " + code);
});
```

If topiclistener is null, the process is gone

Comment: does this work if the process crashes?